# Parsing JSON and creating hashmap

Tags: javascript

I did a function that parse a JSON and create a hashmap to use my data in some operations. The problem that I found, is that my key is repeted several time and in a hashmap there is only one value per key. The way I want it to be, is like this example :

```
12345 : 5
12346 : 4
12346 : 3
```

My function return this : `{ 12345 : 5 , 12346 : 3 }`
So to resume, it overload the key with the last value founded.

In my case i need all this value, so I want to have a result like this :

Result =>

```
{ 12345 : 5 , 12346 : [4,3] }
```

Objective : if I find another key, I should change the value into an array and not overload it.

Here is my function :

```
getFacingCount: function(iSceneGraph){
                var facingArray = {};
                if (iSceneGraph.children.length > 0){
                    for (var i = 0; i < iSceneGraph.children.length; i++){
                        facingArray = Object.assign(facingArray, this.getFacingCount(iSceneGraph.children[i]));
                    }
                }
                if (iSceneGraph.merch.type === "Facing"){
                    facingArray[iSceneGraph.merch.ean] = iSceneGraph.merch.hcount;
                }
                return facingArray;
            }
```

Comment: I recommend to have a consistent structure of hashmap data, e.g. 12345:[5],12346:[3,4] so you could always do hashmap[12345].forEach

Comment: Do you now need to have this kind of result: `{ 12345: [[1, 2, 3]], 12346: [ [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9] ] }` or this kind of result `{ 12345: [1, 2, 3], 12346: [4, 5, 6, 7, 8 , 9] }` ? If you want the latter then I have updated my answer below

Comment: Imposible to have an object with repeated property names: `{12345 : 5, 12346 : 4, 12346 : 3}` and that is why you get as result: `{ 12345 : 5 , 12346 : 3 }`

Comment: I assume in my answer that you JSON looks like an array of objects: `[{12345: 5}, {12346: 4}, {12346: 3}]`.... Can you post your data please?

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding the value here:

```
if (iSceneGraph.merch.type === "Facing"){
    facingArray[iSceneGraph.merch.ean] = iSceneGraph.merch.hcount;
}
```

You need to change those to (based on what you want): ***First Solution***

```
if (iSceneGraph.merch.type === "Facing" && (facingArray[iSceneGraph.merch.ean] == undefined || facingArray[iSceneGraph.merch.ean] == null)){
    facingArray[iSceneGraph.merch.ean] = iSceneGraph.merch.hcount;
} else if (iSceneGraph.merch.type === "Facing" && Array.isArray(facingArray[iSceneGraph.merch.ean])){
    facingArray[iSceneGraph.merch.ean].push(iSceneGraph.merch.hcount);
} else if (iSceneGraph.merch.type === "Facing") {
    facingArray[iSceneGraph.merch.ean] = [facingArray[iSceneGraph.merch.ean]];
    facingArray[iSceneGraph.merch.ean].push(iSceneGraph.merch.hcount);
}
```

But in my opinion, I'd prefer that you have a consistent structure of hashmap data just like the comment from Jonas says, and your solution is going to be like this: ***Second Solution***

```
if (iSceneGraph.merch.type === "Facing"){
    if (facingArray[iSceneGraph.merch.ean] == undefined || facingArray[iSceneGraph.merch.ean] == null) {
        facingArray[iSceneGraph.merch.ean] = [];
    }

    facingArray[iSceneGraph.merch.ean].push(iSceneGraph.merch.hcount);
}
```

If you have a consistent structure of hashmap data, you will be able to handle the data way more easier. See my first solution, it has three condition while the second solution only need two condition. A consistent structure of data allows you to not thinking on the "how you should handle all of the possible types in the data".

**----------- UPDATE -----------------**

Answering your feedback, if you now want to push an array instead of an integer, you can change

```
// `positionList` is an array of integer
facingArray[iSceneGraph.merch.ean].push(positionList);
```

into

```
facingArray[iSceneGraph.merch.ean] = facingArray[iSceneGraph.merch.ean].concat(positionList);
```

The result will be in this format: `{ 12345: [1,2,3], 12346: [4,5,6,7,8,9] }`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your JSON looks like an array of objects: `[{12345: 5}, {12346: 4}, {12346: 3}]` you can use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
var json = [{12345: 5}, {12346: 4}, {12346: 3}],
    result = json.reduce(function (acc, obj) {
      var key = Object.keys(obj);
      acc[key] = !acc[key] ? obj[key] : [].concat(acc[key], obj[key]);
      return acc;
    }, {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: this is not what i'm looking for, i don't even have those values.. check my function

Comment: Is this the structure of your JSON: `[{12345: 5}, {12346: 4}, {12346: 3}]`?